# Указывать ли SELECT при выборки из БД?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть таблица с 5 столбцами в MySQL, мне для вывода нужно только 3 столбца, есть ли смысл делать select('name,desc,date'), или лучше просто без SELECT, пусть возьмёт все 5 столбцов, даже если их не используем. На что это влияет? Производительность? Скорость?
Всегда ли нужно select, если нужно не все столбцы?

Надеюсь суть вопроса правильно изложил.

Comment: Представим две ситуации: когда select используется и когда нет. Они оба возвращают абсолютно идентичные данные. Теперь вопрос: откуда взяться какой-либо заметной экономии, если самая тяжелая часть выполняется идентично?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам оператор SELECT в любом случае указывается, если чистый SQL...

Что же касается того, надо ли конкретно указывать выбираемые столбцы - да надо. Это влияет не столько на производительность самой базы данных(она хорошо оптимизирована, тут важнее как составлен запрос), сколько на производительность сети. Ведь каждый раз при выборке вы посылаете пакеты поочередно по сети и чем больше объем данных, тем больше вы за него платите на хостинге и тем сильнее это сказывается на времени передачи и загруженности сервера. Если же используются еще кэширование, то добавляется еще его нерациональное использование. На маленьких проектах это мало заметно, но чем более нагружен проект, тем сильнее это ощущается.

Comment: Большое спасибо за чёткий и понятный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если в таблице есть вычислимые поля, то их включают в SELECT только если они используются в конкретном случае, потому что иначе лишние вычисления
2. Если есть TEXT/CLOB/BLOB поля, стараются их не включать без необходимости, потому что иначе лишние дескрипторы ресурсов
3. Если в таблице слишком много полей (встречался с 40+ колонок), то для запроса **SELECT *** итоговый объём данных каждой строки будет больше

Поэтому есть правило: выбирать только те поля, которые нужны для каждого конкретного случая